# How to add class in wijmo combo box

Tags: javascript, combobox, wijmo

I need to add the styling to dropdown values on mouseover. To achieve it I need to add class to dropdown.

Is there any other way to fix the issue?
fiddle here jsfiddle.net/37GHw/165

Comment: [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/37GHw/165

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You could override the existing css class of the dropdown items and provide your own styling.

```
.wj-listbox-item:hover {
   background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Please check the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/37GHw/177/